# Writing a function in in R

Tags: r, function, loops

I am doing an exercise to practice writing functions.

I'm trying to figure out the general code before writing the function that reproduces the output from the `table` function. So far, I have the following:

```
set.seed(111) 
vec <- as.integer(runif(10, 5, 20)) 

x <- sort(unique(vec))

for (i in x) {
   c <- length(x[i] == vec[i]) 
   print(c) 
}
```

But this gives me the following output:

```
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
```

I don't think I'm subsetting correctly in my loop. I've been watching videos, but I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong. Would appreciate any insight!

Thanks!

Comment: Cheating: `"names<-"(tabulate(vec), sort(unique(vec)))`, cheating because "tabulate is the workhorse for the `table` function.", see `?tabulate`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can `sum` the logical vector concatenate it to `count`

```
count <- c()
for(number in x) count <- c(count, sum(vec == number)) 
count
#[1] 3 1 4 1 5 4 3 2 7
```

---

In the OP's `for` loop, it is looping over the 'x' values and not on the sequence of 'x'

If we do

```
for(number in x) count <- c(count, length(vec[vec == number]))
```

it should work as well

Comment: @user12310746 in your code, the 'count' object seems to be created on the fly.  and it is updated on each loop, so, it would be length 1 and the. value is replaced at each loop. So, if you check the 'count', it would be the value of the last iteration.  Otherwise, you can also create a `count <- numeric(length(x))` and then loop over the sequence of 'x' i.e. `for(i in seq_along(x)) count[i] <- sum(vec == x[i1])`

Answer (score 0):

You can try `sapply` + `setNames` to achieve the same result like `table`, i.e.,

```
count <- sapply(x, function(k) setNames(sum(k==vec),k))
```

or

```
count <- sapply(x, function(k) setNames(length(na.omit(match(vec,k))),k))
```

such that

```
> count
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
3 1 4 1 5 4 3 2 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without using `unique` and with one pass through the vector (if only `R` was fast with `for` loops!):

```
count = list()
for (i in vec) {
  val = as.character(i)
  if (is.null(count[[val]]))
    count[[val]] = 1
  else
    count[[val]] =  count[[val]] + 1
}
unlist(count)
```